# How to extract td value from webage using Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm pretty much brand new to Python, but I'm looking to build a web-scraping tool that will rip data from an HTML table online and print it into a CSV in the same format.

I am trying to scrape data from web page. But it is giving me empty array though the data is present in it. How to extract that data?

```
enter code here

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

from urllib.request import urlopen

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.forbes.com/global2000/list/#tab:overall"
page = urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
text = soup.get_text()
print(soup.prettify())

all_tables=soup.find_all('tbody')
print(all_tables)
right_table=soup.find('tbody',{"class":'list-item-template'})

A=[]
B=[]
C=[]
D=[]
E=[]
F=[]
G=[]
H=[]
for row in right_table.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll('td')
    print(len(cells))
    states=row.findAll('th') #To store second column data
    if len(cells)==8: #Only extract table body not heading
        A.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
        # B.append(states[0].find(text=True))
        B.append(cells[1].find(text=True))
        C.append(cells[2].find(text=True))
        D.append(cells[3].find(text=True))
        E.append(cells[4].find(text=True))
        F.append(cells[5].find(text=True))
        G.append(cells[6].find(text=True))
        H.append(cells[7].find(text=True))


df=pd.DataFrame(A,columns=['IMAGE'])
df['RANK']=B
df['NAME']=C
df['COUNTRY']=D
df['REVENUE']=E
df['PROFITS']=F
df['ASSETS']=G
print(df)
```

I am getting this output:

[image]

Comment: There is no data on the page. It's built with JavaScript after the page loads. Try opening the page and then right click and _View Page Source_. You'll see no tables there, only a small template.

Comment: Just from the fragment in the URL it is clear that you have a Javascript based site. You might find some useful AJAX calls with browsers network debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has to run to populate the page and you may be presented with a cookie consent. The following navigates that and allows time for various actions to be performed:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

url = 'https://www.forbes.com/global2000/list/#tab:overall'
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get(url)
d.switch_to.frame(d.find_element_by_css_selector('[id^="pop-frame"]'))
WebDriverWait(d, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".call"))).click()
element = WebDriverWait(d, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR , '.legalese')))
actions = ActionChains(d)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
table = d.find_element_by_css_selector('#the_list')
print(table.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have somme trouble because your HTML is not loaded when you are trying to scrap it.
You have to wait the execution of the js part.
One of the simpliest way is to use selenium and to wait the page load

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# coding: utf8

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

from urllib.request import urlopen

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


url = "https://www.forbes.com/global2000/list/#tab:overall"

# Load the javascript part
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
html = driver.page_source

soup  = BeautifulSoup(html)

text = soup.get_text()
print(soup.prettify())

all_tables=soup.find_all('tbody')
print(all_tables)
right_table=soup.find('tbody',{"class":'list-item-template'})

A=[]
B=[]
C=[]
D=[]
E=[]
F=[]
G=[]
H=[]
print(right_table)
for row in right_table.findAll("tr"):
    cells = row.findAll('td')
    print(len(cells))
    states=row.findAll('th') #To store second column data
    if len(cells)==8: #Only extract table body not heading
        A.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
        # B.append(states[0].find(text=True))
        B.append(cells[1].find(text=True))
        C.append(cells[2].find(text=True))
        D.append(cells[3].find(text=True))
        E.append(cells[4].find(text=True))
        F.append(cells[5].find(text=True))
        G.append(cells[6].find(text=True))


df=pd.DataFrame(A,columns=['IMAGE'])
df['RANK']=B
df['NAME']=C
df['COUNTRY']=D
df['REVENUE']=E
df['PROFITS']=F
df['ASSETS']=G
print(df)
```

Comment: its again giving the same output.